# Reverse Engineering Legacy iPod Click Wheel Games

Tags: ipod

I have recently found a bunch of old iPod (pre-touch) games.  These `ipg` files (similar to modern iOS `ipa` files).  Are application bundles which contain resources (images, music files, textures), sometimes a localized strings file, and executables.

Each bundle contains a Manifest.plist file, with executable information.  Below is the manifest for Bomberman 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BuildIdentifier</key>
    <string>1465338237-ae7bdef1533
</string>
    <key>Files</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Digest</key>
            <string>D576EBCA193EA6C08060394435497CBE52288730</string>
            <key>Path</key>
            <string>bombLaunchm25.raw.lcd5</string>
            <key>Size</key>
            <integer>138256</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>DRM</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Digest</key>
            <string>10A5CD8E82B692D4A3136753639FFE9EC96F9E72</string>
            <key>Path</key>
            <string>Executables/iPodBomberman_7052137.bin</string>
            <key>Size</key>
            <integer>425664</integer>
            <key>Verify</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Digest</key>
            <string>3DBFC1556706CF12555448CC5103FCCB59E6E773</string>
            <key>Path</key>
            <string>bombLaunchm1a.raw.lcd5</string>
            <key>Size</key>
            <integer>6176</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>DRM</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Digest</key>
            <string>99B99192D77939DAB9A7E05AEB9ED564D33ECFDB</string>
            <key>Path</key>
            <string>Executables/iPodBomberman_7052208.bin</string>
            <key>Size</key>
            <integer>633344</integer>
            <key>Verify</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>GUID</key>
    <string>20000</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Bomberman</string>
    <key>Platforms</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>BuildID</key>
            <integer>7052137</integer>
            <key>ExecutablePath</key>
            <string>Executables/iPodBomberman_7052137.bin</string>
            <key>LaunchingArtwork</key>
            <string>bombLaunchm25.raw.lcd5</string>
            <key>PlatformID</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>PlatformVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>Size</key>
            <integer>425664</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>BuildID</key>
            <integer>7052208</integer>
            <key>ExecutablePath</key>
            <string>Executables/iPodBomberman_7052208.bin</string>
            <key>LaunchingArtwork</key>
            <string>bombLaunchm1a.raw.lcd5</string>
            <key>PlatformID</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>PlatformVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>Size</key>
            <integer>633344</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>BuildID</key>
            <integer>7052208</integer>
            <key>ExecutablePath</key>
            <string>Executables/iPodBomberman_7052208.bin</string>
            <key>LaunchingArtwork</key>
            <string>bombLaunchm1a.raw.lcd5</string>
            <key>PlatformID</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <key>PlatformVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>Size</key>
            <integer>633344</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>Version</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The Manifest appears to contain two different builds (one is listed twice), presumably for two different iPod architectures (?).  For each executable there also appears to be an accompanying `.bin.sinf` file, which I believe contains purchaser information used by Apple's FairPlay DRM.

Here's where I get stuck:

- Running `strings` on either of the executables, `.bin.sinf` files, or the `.raw.lcd5` files prints garbage.
- Running `nm` gives me an error that the files are not object files.
- `file` just tells me that the files are binary data.
- I cannot use `otool` because the files are not Mach-O binaries.

According to Wikipedia, all iPods before the 6th gen classic used an ARM processor (one or more 7TDMI-derived CPUs).

What are my options for dissembling or reading any of the information (strings, etc) of these executables and binary files?

Comment: Modern IPA files are *heavily* encrypted. Could it be the same for these old files? Your search for plain text strings seems to indicate that.

Comment: @RadLexus That could be the case.  All of the binaries should be the same for all purchasers, but the `sinf` contain purchaser-specific keys to start the executable.  But wouldn't it be odd for all the binary files in the bundle to be encrypted?  Surely the game data should be somehow visible.